# The "NoMethodError" error while saving the nested resources form in Rails 3, using DataMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datamapper

In my controller I have:

```
def index
 @owner = current_user
 @accounts = @owner.accounts.all( :name.not => nil )
 @aliases = @owner.aliases.all( :id.not => nil )
 @transfer = @accounts.transfers.new()
end

def create 
@owner = current_user
 @account = @owner.accounts.first(:id => params[:account_id])
 @alias_out = @owner.aliases.first( :id => params[:alias_from]) 
 @alias_in = Alias.first( :id => params[:alias_to]) 

   @transfer =  @account.transfers.create(params[:transfer])  
                @alias_in.update(:transfers_in => params[:transfer]) 
                @alias_out.update(:transfers_out => params[:transfer])
```

in my view:

```
<div id="accounts_list">
   <h2>Your accounts</h2>
    <% @accounts.each do |acc| %>
    <div class="each_element">
      <h3><u><%= acc.name%></u></h3>
      <b>Available money: <u><%= acc.value%> <%=acc.currency%></u></b>
      <div id="create_account">
         <h2>Create an transfer</h2>
    <%= form_for([acc, @transfer]) do |trans_form|%>
         <%= trans_form.label :amount %>
        <%= trans_form.text_field :amount %></br>
        <%= trans_form.fields_for :alias_from do |alias_from|%>
        <%= alias_from.label :alias_from %>
        <%= alias_from.collection_select :id, @aliases, :id, :id %> </br>
        <%end%>
        <%= trans_form.fields_for :alias_to do |alias_to|%>
        <%= alias_to.label :alias_to %>
        <%= alias_to.text_field :id %></br>
        <%end%>
        <%= trans_form.text_area :comment, :rows=>5 %></br>
        <%= trans_form.submit :value => "Transfer" %>
         <%end%>
        </div>
    </div>

    <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

and in my models

```
class Transfer
  include DataMapper::Resource


  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :alias_from, "Alias", :key =>true
  belongs_to :alias_to, "Alias", :key =>true 



   property :id, Serial
      property :amount, Integer, :required => true
      property :comment, Text


    end

    class Alias
  include DataMapper::Resource


  belongs_to :user
  has n, :transfers_in, "Transfer"  
  has n, :transfers_out, "Transfer"   

  property :id, String, :key => true, :unique => true

  validates_format_of :id, :with => /[0-9a-z\-]/i

end
```

All this results for me with

> ```
> Started POST "/accounts/2/transfers" for 127.0.0.1
> ```
>
> at 2011-06-20 09:16:25 +0400
>         Processing by TransfersController#create as HTML
>         Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"token",
>   "transfer"=>{"amount"=>"30.3",
>   "alias_from"=>{"id"=>"My Alias"},
>   "alias_to"=>{"id"=>"His Alias"},
>   "comment"=>"comment text"},
>   "commit"=>"Transfer",
>   "account_id"=>"2"}
>        ~   SQL (0.525ms)  SELECT "id", "encrypted_password",
>   "remember_created_at",
>   "reset_password_token",
>   "reset_password_sent_at",
>   "failed_attempts", "unlock_token",
>   "locked_at", "sign_in_count",
>   "current_sign_in_at",
>   "last_sign_in_at",
>   "current_sign_in_ip",
>   "last_sign_in_ip", "username",
>   "email", "name", "country" FROM
>   "users" WHERE "id" IN (2) LIMIT 1
>        ~   SQL (0.495ms)  SELECT "id", "name", "currency", "value", "user_id"
>   FROM "accounts" WHERE ("user_id" = 2
>   AND "id" = 2) ORDER BY "id" LIMIT 1
>        ~   SQL (0.414ms)  SELECT "id" FROM "aliases" WHERE "id" = 'My Alias'
>   ORDER BY "id" LIMIT 1
>        ~   SQL (0.329ms)  SELECT "id" FROM "aliases" WHERE "id" =
>   'His Alias' ORDER BY "id" LIMIT 1
>       Completed   in 15ms
>
> ```
> NoMethodError (undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass):
>   app/controllers/transfers_controller.rb:10:in
> ```
>
> `create'

And I have no idea what might be the problem. Any suggestions? Would really appreciate.

Comment: Hm, why do you thunk the problem is in it? What would be the proper way to this specific account?

Comment: well, by my logic,  `@account = @owner.accounts.all(:id => :account_id)` means that from all accounts of this member we take the one with the proper id, and `params[:transfer]` is the parameters from the form -  `{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jgZw", "transfer"=>{"amount"=>"30.3", "alias_from"=>{"id"=>"MyAlias"}, "alias_to"=>{"id"=>"PayMe"}, "comment"=>"comment text"}, "commit"=>"Transfer", "account_id"=>"2"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mu is too short is right: the [`all`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/dm-core/1.1.0/DataMapper/Collection#all-instance_method) method returns a collection, not a single object. Instead you have to use [`first`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/dm-core/1.1.0/DataMapper/Collection#first-instance_method):

```
@account = @owner.accounts.first(:id => :account_id)
```

Or [`get`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/dm-core/1.1.0/DataMapper/Collection#get-instance_method):

```
@account = @owner.accounts.get(account_id)
```

**Update, based on comment:**

You are trying to update aliases, but this is not necessary. A `transfer` belongs to an `alias_from` and to an `alias_to`. This means your tranfers table should have two columns: `alias_from_id` and `alias_to_id`. That's where you store those values.

You don't have do use `fields_for`. So, instead of:

```
<%= trans_form.fields_for :alias_from do |alias_from|%>
  <%= alias_from.label :alias_from %>
  <%= alias_from.collection_select :id, @aliases, :id, :id %> </br>
<%end%>
<%= trans_form.fields_for :alias_to do |alias_to|%>
  <%= alias_to.label :alias_to %>
  <%= alias_to.text_field :id %></br>
<%end%>
```

You should be able to simply do:

```
<%= trans_form.label :alias_from %>
<%= trans_form.collection_select :alias_from_id, @aliases, :id, :id %> </br>
<%= trans_form.label :alias_to %>
<%= trans_form.text_field :alias_to_id %></br>
```

And your controller action should look like this:

```
def create 
  @owner = current_user
  @account = @owner.accounts.first(:id => params[:account_id])
  @transfer =  @account.transfers.create(params[:transfer])  

  # the rest of your code...
end
```

**Update 2**

You can set the correct names of your foreign key fields in your model like this:

```
class Transfer
  include DataMapper::Resource    

  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :alias_from, "Alias", :key => true, :child_key => 'alias_from_id'
  belongs_to :alias_to, "Alias", :key => true, :child_key => 'alias_to_id'

  # Etc...
```

Comment: Mischa and Mu are correct. You are using a collection when you should be using a singular object. Get or First are the methods you should use.

Comment: Yup, this seems right, thank you. But now i'm having `undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass`. I've edited the code and logs. Do I even need the to update manually, or association is doing it automatically?

Comment: @Maay, I updated my answer. Do you understand what I am saying?

Comment: I do understand all you'r saying, thank you, it does make sense. I've changed form and added two columns to the transfer model (`alias_from_id` and `alias_to_id`), but now it's throwing me the `ERROR:  null value in column "alias_id" violates not-null constraint` error, but now I understand that just have to read more about associations. Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: @Maay, You are welcome. The error message you are getting now has to do with the fact that `alias_from_id` and `alias_to_id` aren't the default. In your alias model you have to specify the name of the foreign key like this: `:child_key => :alias_from_id`. See my updated answer.

Comment: yup, i've realized it on my own just 10 minutes ago, thank you again. i'll be back in 10 hours to award with bounty.